# Ubuntu One 2FA lost device removal

Tags: ubuntu-one, two-factor-authentication

I lost access to my Google Authenticator app and my backups aren't working...lesson learned.  Now I need to remove the 2FA device from my Ubuntu One account but of course you have to have the device to remove it #infiniteloop

I have followed all the steps in the FAQ, including 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSO/FAQs/2FA?_ga=2.106505859.1607882417.1522604854-253479208.1522604854#No.2C_I.27m_really_locked_out_of_my_account.__What_should_I_do.3F

But they never reply to my emails...ever...have been trying for months..not kidding...MONTHS...to get this resolved.

Also tried IRC, nothing.  Trying here in off chance someone will know something that can help.

Thoughts?

UPDATE:
I'll update this periodically.  I have little hope for getting this resolved...curious just how long they will ignore me...lol.

UPDATE (4/11/2018):  Resent email today as a reply to their latest automated response from 10 days ago.

---

Hi,

This message is automatically generated to let you know that we received your support request. You don't need to do anything else right now.

Your request has been assigned a number of: Ubuntu Single Sign-On #76225. If you have additional information you'd like to provide us with about about this request, simply reply to this email.

We'll be in touch soon.

### Canonical ISD Support

Comment: Are you still logged in on Launchpad, or has the cookie expired?

Comment: I can login...just not remove the old 2FA device.  I can even change my password...which is very weird.

Comment: If you are logged in on Launchpad, I think you can remove yourself from the https://launchpad.net/~sso-2f-testers team, which will disable 2FA on your account, but to be able to manage the 2FA devices, you will need to be in that group and will need a valid token when logging in, or you will have to get Canonical support/IS to fix your account for you and reset the 2FA.

Comment: Nope, now I think my cookie has expired, I'm stuck at the 2FA page again.  Is getting completely zero response from the the SSO team normal?  Doesn't Canonical help/care at all?  I get community support for most things, but this has been months.  Seems really bad to me.  But thank you for at least trying dobey...you are the only one that did!!

Comment: It is not normal, or at least didn't used to be. Where did you ask in IRC exactly?